# h:outputText force word wrap early

Tags: string, jsf

I am having an issue where a field can be quite long (240 characters) and it causes some UI issues when displaying.  Would it be possible to force a word wrap every 80 chars?

```
<s:decorate>
   <ui:param name="labelWidth" value="130px" />
   <ui:define name="label">Summary:</ui:define>
   <h:outputText value="#{myView.myBean.summary}"/>
</s:decorate>
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Desired:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for [word-wrap CSS property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp).